# Xamarin ios app to run on Mac with mac-catalyst

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

we're currently wrapping up our cross platform xamarin forms app that is being deployed on android, UWP and iOS.

Just wondering with the introduction of Mac Catalyst has anyone had any success or information on making their xamarin ios app run natively on the mac using this feature or would they just be using xamarin.mac?

Comment: https://twitter.com/praeclarum/status/1325487486915637248

Answer (score 1):

Through this [thread](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6206), it looks like the mac-catalyst of xcode11-feature has not been supported so far.

And you can follow [this issue link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6210) to track the process of adding support for Catalyst.

Answer (score 1):

Will be available with .NET 6 this Fall (2021). According to their [plan](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8955).